# Why I have 2 'Documents' and 2 'Images' folders in my User folder?

Tags: windows-10, public-folders

I have customized my desktop using `Customize\Theme\Icon Parameters` to add a specifific icon for User folder.

When I click on this icon, `Windows File Explorer` is loaded and I can see 2 folders names `Documents` (or I suppose 'My Folder' in english) and 2 folders `Images` (or I suppose 'My Picture' in english).

When I right click on first `Documents` folder I can see a tab named `Location` in which it is written `c:\Users\schlebe\OneDrive\Documents`.

When I right click on second, the `Location` tab is not present ! I can only see that `Documents` folder is `c:\Users\schlebe` folder.

This is the same thing for `Images` folder.

**Why ìs there 2 folders with same name ?**

Which of them is original Windows `Documents` folder ?

Which of them can I remove ?

PS: when I go to `c:\Users\schlebe` I can see only 1 `Documents` folder and 1 `Images` folder.

PS: `dir /AH` DOS command entered from User directory return some Junctions but no Junction has been defined for `Documents` or `Images` folders.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the other Documents & Images folders under `c:\Users\schlebe\OneDrive`.

The reason you see both under your UserProfile folder on the Desktop is that that is a *virtual folder*, similar to **Network** or **Control Panel**. It contains both the contents of your ***UserProfile*** folder found under C:\Users and, if any of the User Shell Folders found under **This PC** have been redirected, in this case to the **OneDrive** folder, icons for those will appear as well.
When you open Documents or Images from **This PC**, which folders open?